# WordPress custom post type: Query by id works, by post_name doesn't

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I would need some help with Wordpress and custom post types/permalinks.

I registered custom post type by the name "services" with the following arguments:

```
$args = array(
  'labels' => $labels,
  'singular_label' => __('services'),
  'public' => true,
  'query_var' => true,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/wp-menu-ico.png',
  'menu_position' => null,
  'capability_type' => 'page',
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'services', 'with_front' => TRUE),
  'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes')
);
```

Now I create new post by the title of "Make up" and slug "make-up". When I try to preview this post from WP dashboard using the Preview link it gives me 404. I can't query this post from outside the dashboard too.

Now I found that when I use the following url structure it shows me the post: 
`/?post_type=services&p=243`

This however doesn't work: `/?services=make-up`

What I'm trying to do is to use pretty urls with custom post type, which doesn't work. I disabled the pretty permalinks in WP options and still doesn't work.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like it is a problem with your permalinks settings if it works with the correct query parameters. What are your permalink settings?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `Settings > permalinks` and hit `Save Changes` button. and preview your custom post again