# Custom Permalink of Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I register a new Custom Post Type with:

```
register_post_type('abcd_film',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Films' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Film' )
        ),
        'description'   => 'Manage the Films',
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', ),
        'public'        => true,
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'rewrite'       => array('slug' => 'films'),
    )
);
```

My WordPress is located at ( dummy link ) :

> www.example.com/folder/wordpress/

My permalink setting is ( the "Post Name" option ):

> www.example.com/folder/wordpress/%postname%/

However, I create a new custom post under the custom post type "Films" with post name "Apple", the link shows **404 File Not Found**. The `.htaccess` file is writable by WordPress & the current content written by WordPress is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /folder/wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I double checked with `phpinfo()`, the `mod_rewrite()` module is in "Loaded Module" section. Also, I tried to refresh the Permalink settings in WordPress `Admin > General > Permalink > Save Changes`.

404 Not Found still persists. What else can I do?

Tried the followings:

1. add `publicly_queryable` with value `true` to options array  ( *it's not required, as `public` is already set to `true` and default value of `publicly_queryable` is equal to the value of `public`* )
2. add `with_front` with value `true` to `rewrite` sub-array ( *it's not required too, as the default value of `with_front` is `true` )
3. add `flush_rewrite_rules(false);` after `register_post_type()`

All the above tries have no effect. Cache is already disabled & flushed.

Reference Questions:

- [WordPress Custom Permalink Structure for: Pages, Posts and Custom Post Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263407/wordpress-custom-permalink-structure-for-pages-posts-and-custom-post-types)
- [permalink structure for single-{post-type}.php in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050148/permalink-structure-for-single-post-type-php-in-wordpress)
- [WordPress custom post type: Query by id works, by post_name doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667171/wordpress-custom-post-type-query-by-id-works-by-post-name-doesnt)

Comment: Did you try to put `flush_rewrite_rules( false ); ` just after?? also, what happens if you change permalink structure ? and do you have `'publicly_queryable' => true,`

Comment: After adding `'publicly_queryable' => true` & `flush_rewrite_rules( false );` & cleared cache, still 404 Not Found...

Comment: ok.. last thing that I can think of now is to try also `'rewrite' => array("slug" => "films","with_front" => true), ` combined with the others . I had the same problem about two weeks ago, but I can not remember just where the culprit was . and please post result of permalink structure change to default ..

Comment: Also - how do you access that page ? through a menu item ?

Comment: Add a new post in Custom Post through WordPress menu. Then click "View Post"

Comment: `with_front` option has no effect too

Comment: "Add a new post in Custom Post through WordPress menu." - and the URL is ok ?? is the post saved ? draft ? preview ?

Comment: Post is saved & published. Cannot preview. However, using non- URL friendly permalink ( e.g. example.com/wordpress/?custom_post_type=123 , it works.

Comment: ok. the only last thing I am going to try before giving up ( and post the whole of my working code for you ) is to ask if you have tried to wrap it all in  `add_action( 'init', 'your_custom_with_action_register_post' );`..

Comment: Yes, the whole function is in `add_action('init', ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not due to WordPress configuration or PHP configuration. The reason of `.htaccess` not working is: In my Apache virtual host settings, it is configured to ignore `.htaccess` by:

```
AllowOverride None
```

To disable this lock, change the value in the virtual host file ( in `sites-enabled` folder ) to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

then **restart** Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome to test this you will want to make sure your browser cache is emptied.  Use the Chrome menu to empty the cache.  This has bitten me more than once.  I clear the cache, exit Chrome, re-access the site.

I've also had issues with Save Changes on permalinks not flushing the permalinks table.   Change to the default post ID post type than back to your normal post type.

The other issue I've run into with my customer base is a WordPress theme that is augmenting the permalink rules.   If not done correctly it can cause custom post types to malfunction.    Try a default WordPress theme like Twenty Thirteen.

If all else fails start with a test site with a clean WordPress 3.6 install, add your custom post type and NOTHING else (no theme changes or extra plugins).   That will eliminate all other variables and let you focus on server and system rules.  Seems like you've already ruled that out, however.

Good luck & remember to share your answer if you find it on your own.